# Setting values to EMPTY but not NULL by default in C#

Tags: c#

I have a `Mainclass` in my code with various a list and various subset. When I try

```
main k = new main();
k.main.addressinfo.addressline1 = "XXX";
```

I am getting the error "Object reference not set to an instance of an object// NULLEXCEPTION."

```
public class Mainclass
{
    public List<main> mainset { get; set; }
 // do sth to load and save model info
}
 public class main
{
    public personalinfo info { get; set; }
    public addressinfo currentaddr { get; set; }
    public addressinfo[] otheraddr { get; set; }
    public telephone currenttel { get; set; }
    public telephone[] othertel { get; set; }
 }
public class addressinfo
{
    public string Addressline1 { get; set; } 
    public string Addressline2 { get; set; }
    public string City { get; set; }
    public string postcode { get; set; 
}
public class telephone
{
    public int tel { get; set; }
}
```

Since the Class contains lists and arrays I am a little confused as to how to set the default values of string to EMPTY but not NULL. Also How do I ensure that the Childrens by default have One EMPTY but not NULL Object?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to initialize your objects

```
public personalinfo info = new personalinfo();
public addressinfo currentaddr = new addressinfo();
public telephone currenttel = new telephone();
```

Comment: I know but what about the Arrays? Do I need to initialize them as well?

Comment: Yes, it would help. Like this: `public addressinfo[] otheraddr = new addressinfo[2] {new addressinfo(), new addressinfo()};` All `class`es need to be initialized, `struct`s do not. (EG, int and string are both `struct`s)

Comment: @mcmonkey4eva [`System.String`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.aspx) is a class, not a struct.

Comment: @Lukazoid - ... oh yeah, it is. Woops. Wasn't thinking. Yeah strings need to be initializing too, but it'll let you get away with just `public string mystring = "";` instead of `new string();` or anything like that.

Answer (score 0):

You have to define [constructors](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ace5hbzh.aspx) for your classes and inside them set the properties to their default values.

Answer (score 0):

`@Using mcmonkey4eva` Answer

```
public personalinfo info = new personalinfo();
public addressinfo currentaddr = new addressinfo();
public telephone currenttel = new telephone();

public addressinfo[] otheraddr = new addressinfo[1];
public List<main> mainset = new List<main>();
```

Comment: If mcmonkey4eva's answer was the one that helped you the most, you should accept the answer.

Comment: What Tim said - also, `public addressinfo[] otheraddr = new addressinfo[1];` should probably be `public addressinfo[] otheraddr = new addressinfo[1] { new addressinfo(); };`, otherwise it will be an array containing only a null.

Comment: Didnt not realise that the *Correct* symbol was to mark as answer :

Comment: Changed arrays to list to overcome problems that Tim pointed out.